# Trying to add a value to variable inside a stored procedure using the select statement

Tags: mysql, variables, select, set, procedure

I cannot figure out the proper syntax in this stored procedure.  I declared the Course_id variable.  One of the input values to the stored procedure is named csi.  I want to use value of csi to lookup a value in another table.  I am trying to retrieve the course_id from a table named course_schedule.  If you look at the first SELECT statement in this procedure you'll see what I'm trying to do.  I have tried different ways of syntax in the statement, but I can't get it to work.
Can someone give me clue where I am going wrong?

Thank you,

Mike Reed

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `ClassRegistration`(IN csi numeric, IN regid numeric, IN area_id numeric, IN comm_id numeric, IN feeamount numeric,  IN status CHAR(50), IN addby CHAR(50), IN addip CHAR(50) )
BEGIN
    DECLARE course_regid INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE course_id INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    
    SELECT course_id INTO @course_id FROM course_schedule WHERE course_sked_id = csi;

    
  INSERT INTO course_registered (course_sked_id, regid, area_id, comm_id, status, feeamount, added, addby, addip, modified, modby, modip) values (csi, regid, area_id, comm_id, status, feeamount, now(), addby, addip, now(), addby, addip );
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO course_regid;
    SELECT course_id;
    
    INSERT INTO student_eval (regid, course_sked_id) values (regid, csi);
    INSERT INTO instructor_eval (regid, course_sked_id) values (regid, csi);
    
    
    END
```

Comment: Showing the error messages would be a big help to those trying to help you. But I'm suspicious of your SELCT statement that seems to be trying to put a set of results into a scalar variable.

Comment: You're determined to use a sproc for this?

Comment: For Jerry, yes I am trying to put a value into that variable course_id.  I want to use that variable to run another insert statement for a different table.

Comment: For Strawberry, I don't know if determined is the right word, but this procedure is being called by other software.  I'm trying to take some of the load off it and have some simple insert statements run within MariaDB.  Is there a better way to do this kind of thing?